# How to display local Pdf file in new browser tab in Angularjs 2?

Tags: angular

Am using angular 2, am trying to display `index.pdf` file placed inside app folder, i am trying to display this Pdf file when user click on link, so that it will be redirected/open local Pdf file in a browser by having new tab (localhost:4200/index.pdf).

```
>     src -> app -> index.pdf
>     src -> app -> app.component.html
```

//Inside app.component.html

```
<a href="index.pdf" target="_blank">PDF</a>
```

Above process is not working,I am new to angular, can any one help/guide me on the right way to achieve this, help would be appreciated.

I found few similar questions, but answers are getting confused or not helped me.

Comment: <a href="/assets/index.pdf" target="_blank">PDF</a> "put your files in assets folder"

Comment: Thanks @prasanth, that is working.